# Module missing while the module trying to import is already there

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-tesseract

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *

image_file = 'E:\Downloads\menu.tiff'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print ("=====output=======\n")
print (text)
```

See the error shows no module is found but the util file is here in the directory of tesseract itself.I have no idea why its happening showing its not found.
[image]

[image]
My question  is extremely simple from inside *init*.py how to import util.py and errors.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package needs a relative import (see [PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)).

A solution would be to replace

```python
import util
import errors
```

by

```python
from . import util
from . import errors
```

This change was introduced in python 2.5 (September 19th 2006), so I totally agree with @DanielRoseman, you should look for another library.
You can find OCR packages on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=ocr%20AND%20tesser&submit=search) or [GitHub](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=python%20ocr%20tesser&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for example.

---

EDIT: corrected typo in module name

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d28bcc4e5d22> in <module>()
      1 from PIL import Image
----> 2 from pytesser import *
      3 
      4 image_file = 'E:\Downloads\menu.tiff'
      5 im = Image.open(image_file)

C:\Users\SACHIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesser\__init__.py in <module>()
      7 import subprocess
      8 
----> 9 from . import utils
     10 from . import errors

Comment: 11 tesseract_exe_name = 'C:\\Users\\SACHIN\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytesser\\tesseract' # Name of executable to be called at command line

ImportError: cannot import name 'utils'

Comment: bro both gives this error I had tried both your solutions beforehand .I was stuck with what to do

Comment: Well, looks like a typo on my side: `utils` should be `util`. Edited answer. Still get the **same** error this way?

Comment: that error changed but the problem is that all the under lying modules have to be corrected now this is the error and upon completion of this there will be no error anymore  File "C:\Users\SACHIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesser\errors.py", line 15
    raise Tesser_General_Exception as text
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: But for your effort I have accepted it as answer and upvoted it

Comment: @SachinDivakar: Thanks. I found an OCR tutorial using a more recent package, maybe it can help with your project. http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/

Comment: I am going through a nightmare .I actually ran it and what I got was PIL missing error .I installed tesseract again ran the sample script shown in that and this is the code https://ideone.com/PLBi5b I have also added the error under the code

Comment: Can you try uninstalling `PIL` and installing `Pillow` instead? It is the replacement for PIL now. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: you want me to unstiall PIL ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153549/discussion-between-fabienp-and-sachin-divakar).

Answer (score 2):

The library you are using appears not to have been touched for more than six years. It is not compatible with Python 3.

Find another library.

Comment: I wasn't programming for a while and I decided to learn python by doing a image to text conversion application .So I am at my wits end with this tried everything realised one thing there is a python 2.7 python 3+ conflict going on.Can you suggest me any alternative for the same .

Comment: I can't really, because I don't know what you are trying to do. What led you to use this specific obscure module?

Comment: Only thing available with a tutorial for windows.